# Update Batch error, need to use set to update

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to update multiple rows in a table. I get this error:

**You must use the "set" method to update an entry.**

Basically I want to be able to update admin rights for all users that are in a form, pulled from a table.

Or what if the users are not in the table how can I insert the if the checkbox is checked? Thanks.

View.php

```
 <? foreach ($users as $user){ ?>
    <h3><?= $user['username']?></h3
    <input style="display:none;" type="text" name="userid[]" id="userid" value=<?=$user['user_id']?>" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="isAdmin[]" id="isAdmin"/>
 <? }?>
```

Controller.php

```
public function permissions()
{   
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
foreach ($this->input->post('userid') as $row){
    $data[$i++]['userid'] = $row;
}

foreach ($this->input->post('isAdmin') as $row){
    $private = convertBooleanToInt($row);
    $data[$j++]['isAdmin'] = $private;
}  

    $this->admin_model->update_admin($data);
}
```

And the Model.php

```
function update_admin()
    {
        $this->db->update_batch('user_roles', $data, 'user');
    }
```

I did a var dump and this is what I get.

array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["user"]=> string(1) "1" ["role"]=> int(1) } [1]=> array(1) { ["user"]=> string(1) "2" } }

Comment: I think your where condition is not working, you need to provide the key of for where condition in array, so your this ```$this->db->update_batch('user_roles', $data, 'user');``` statement, change to this ```$this->db->update_batch('user_roles', $data, 'userid');``` and try once.

Comment: Also, your method name changed... You called this ```$this->admin_model->update_admin($data);``` and your method in model is this ```function update_permissions()```, please correct it.